# STL List to hold structure pointers

Tags: c++, list, stl, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a structure called vertex and I created some pointers to them.  What I want to do is add those pointers to a list.  My code below, when it tries to insert the pointer into the list, creates a segmentation fault.  Can someone please explain what is going on?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

#define NUM_VERTICES 8

using namespace std;

enum { WHITE, GRAY, BLACK };

struct vertex
{
    int color;
    int distance;
    char parent;
};

int main()
{
    //create the vertices
    vertex r = {WHITE, NULL, NULL};

    //create pointer to the vertex structures
    vertex *pr = &r;

    //create a list to hold the vertices
    list<vertex*> *r_list = new list<vertex*>;

    list<vertex*>::iterator it;

    r_list->insert(it, pr);
}
```

Comment: you're missing a return value in the main function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several things wrong here.

First off, you aren't initializing the iterator, like other's have said:

```
list<vertex*>::iterator it = r_list->begin();
```

Do this and your code will be fine. But your code is done in a bad manner.

Why are you allocating the list from the heap? Look at your code: you have a memory leak. You aren't calling `delete r_list` anywhere. This is why you should use smart pointers ([`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) if you have C++11, boost equivalents otherwise : [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) and [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm))

But better yet, just do it on the stack:

```
//create a list to hold the vertices
list<vertex*> r_list;

list<vertex*>::iterator it = r_list->begin();

r_list.insert(it, pr);
```

In addition, using the iterator to insert is going about things the long way. Just use [push front()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_front) or [push back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back):

```
//create a list to hold the vertices
list<vertex*> r_list;

r_list.push_back(pr);
```

Another thing: if your list outlives the vertex you've constructed, it will be pointing to something invalid.

For example:

```
// global
list<vertex*> r_list;

void some_function(void)
{
    //create the vertices
    vertex r = {WHITE, NULL, NULL};

    //create pointer to the vertex structures
    vertex *pr = &r;

    r_list.push_back(pr);
} // right here, vertex r stops existing: the list now contains an
  // invalid pointer.
```

One solution is to store pointers to heap-allocated vertices:

```
// global
list<vertex*> r_list;

void some_function(void)
{
    //create the vertices
    vertex *r = new vertex;
    r->color = WHITE;
    r->distance = 0;
    r->parent = 0;

    r_list.push_back(r);
}
```

Now even after the function the list is pointing to a valid heap-allocated vertex. This now has the problem that when you're done using the list, you need to go through the lsit and call `delete` on each element. This problem is assisted by using the [Boost Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

The best way, though, is to just store vertices themselves (rather than pointers to them):

```
//create a list to hold the vertices
list<vertex> r_list;

//create the vertices
vertex r = {WHITE, NULL, NULL};

r_list.push_back(r);
```

If you give vertex a constructor, you can even just construct them in-place:

```
struct vertex
{
    int color;
    int distance;
    char parent;

    vertex(int _color, int _distance, char _parent) :
    color(_color),
    distance(_distance),
    parent(_parent)
    {
    }
};

//create a list to hold the vertices
list<vertex> r_list;

r_list.push_back(vertex(WHITE, NULL, NULL));
```

(these are now outside your problem)

Firstly, NULL is generally only used when dealing with pointers. Since `distance` and `parent` are not pointers, use `0` to initialize them, rather than `NULL`:

```
//create the vertices
vertex r = {WHITE, 0, 0};
```

Secondly, use `constants` rather than `#define`:

```
#define NUM_VERTICES 8 // <- bad
const int NumberVertices = 8; // <- good
```

Lastly, give your enum a name, or place it in a namespace:

```
enum Color { WHITE, GRAY, BLACK };
```

Hope these help!

Comment: Nice compilation of all the finer points. I'm glad you gave some emphasis on the lifetime of pointers and the difference between allocating on the stack and the heap.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you aren't initializing `it` to anything. Do you mean:

```
list<vertex*>::iterator it = r_list->begin();
```

Also, why are you initializing an int and char to NULL? Usually people use NULL for pointers.

Also, how about naming your enum and benefiting from the type safety of enums, instead of using them as ints?

Also, no need to create a new variable to make a pointer to the vertex. When you call insert, you can pass in `&r`.

Also, as Peter points out, why not just use `push_back()`?

Your code should look more like this:

```
using namespace std;

enum Color { 
    WHITE, 
    GRAY, 
    BLACK 
};

struct vertex
{
    Color color;
    int distance;
    char parent;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //create the vertices
    vertex r = {WHITE, 0, ''};

    //create a list to hold the vertices
    list* r_list = new list();

    list::iterator it = r_list->begin();
    r_list->insert(it, &r);

    // Or even better, use push_back (or front)
    r_list->push_back(&r);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialised the iterator, so it's not valid to insert with. You could use `r_list->push_back(pr)` instead, for example.

Also, the pointers in your list aren't going to be valid once r goes out of scope. Obviously that's not a problem in this case since it's in `main()`, but I assume this isn't the exact example where you're going to use the code, so it may come back to bite you...

Comment: The mingw compiler gave this error when I tried to use push_back()

error: no matching function for call to `std::list<vertex*, std::allocator<vertex*> >::push_back(vertex&)'|

However, it didn't give me that error when I compiled it with g++.  Anyways, I think this topic belongs in another thread.

Comment: That compiler error looks like you might have tried to pass a vertex instead of a vertex* into the push_back method. But I could be wrong...

Comment: That's correct Tom.  Thanks.
I need to get better at reading errors messages

Comment: Ha, it's something that takes time but you will get better at. Don't get scared when you see long stuff like "std::allocator" blah blah (A lot of times you'll get much longer stuff like that). Filter through the junk and get to the meat of it: You have a list<vertex*> and the arg to push_back says vertex&. :-).

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized `it`, so you're inserting at a random/uninitialized place/pointer.

Normal ways of adding items to a `std::list` include its methods `push_back` and `push_front`; you'd normally use `insert` only if you had previously otherwise determined the specific spot in which you want to insert one more item.