# iterate through list of linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am kind of new to c++ and got headache with this pointer and stuff!

I need to iterate through list of struct which is linked list, read the data of struct and pop that entry!

this my struct :

```
struct node {
    map<string,double> candidates;
    double pathCost;
    string source;
    node *next;             // the reference to the next node
};
```

by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085489/stl-list-to-hold-structure-pointers) post I create my list like :

```
list<node*> nodeKeeper;
```

and then initialized the first value:

```
    node *head;
    head= new node;
    head->pathCost = 0.0;
    head->source="head";
    head->next = NULL;
```

thin fill the list and struct :

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sourceSentence.size(); i++){

    node *newNode= new node;             //create a temporary node


    //DO STUFF HERE


    //push currunt node to stack
    nodeKeeper.push_back(newNode);

    head = newNode;

}
```

now I have list of struct and I want to iterate through it and pop the elements:

```
for (list<node*>::const_iterator it=nodeKeeper.begin();it!=nodeKeeper.end();it++){

    it->pop_front();

}
```

which gives me this error:

> error: request for member 'pop_front' in '*
>   it.std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator->()', which is of
>   pointer type 'node* const' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?) make: ***
>   [main3.o] Error 1

It looks like that my iterator points inside the list , not the list itself!

Can you tell me what is wrong here?!

Comment: Why not using a `list` of `list`s, if you're allowed to use STL?

Comment: @bilz Yes I also tried that! I as said I am new to c++, I am just trying everything that read

Comment: @AndyProwl how does that help? I need to have pointer to next node!

Comment: @Moj `list` is a doubly linked list structure. Each element has a pointer to the next and previous node. That is how you iterate over it.

Comment: @Moj: That's what `list` does for you. I would remove the `next` member from `node` and I would use a `list<list<node>>` (or probably a `vector<list<node>>`, unless you have a reason to choose `list`)

Comment: good to know! I would think how to solve my problem by this ! but do you have any idea about this problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have a single list of your node struct, there is no need to manage next pointers your self. Inserting would stay the same (minus the `head =` line)

To pop all element of the list you would do something like

```
int sizeOfList = nodeKeeper.size();
for( int i =0; i < sizeOfList; i++) {
    //if you want to do something with the last element
    node * temp = nodeKeeper.back();
    //do stuff with that node

    //done with the node free the memory
    delete temp;
    nodeKeeper.pop_back();
}
```

Compiling/running example here: http://ideone.com/p6UlyN

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is remove the elements, use [`std::list::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/clear):

```
nodeKeeper.clear();
```

---

To read the contents of the element, then remove, try this:

```
for (std::list<node*>::const_iterator it = nodeKeeper.begin(); it != nodeKeeper.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << (*it)->source;
    // do more reading

    nodeKeeper.pop_front();
}
```

or with C++11:

```
for (const auto& a : nodeKeeper) {
    std::cout << a->source;

    nodeKeeper.pop_front();
}
```

Comment: @juanchopanza wasn't aware of that method. I'll use it in my answer. thx

Comment: how can I access to data  of each element ? something like :         nodeKeeper.front()->source;
because right now it just prints the last element which "head"

Comment: @Moj I'm updating my answer. hold on plz

Comment: Sorry I guess I couldn't explain my problem well. Actually I need to pop each element in loop, because in my program I need to use the top element , remove it and then going to next element . that mean in each iteration I should have it->front()->source, it->pop_front() This code goes through the list , read the data, at after loop clear the list.

Comment: @Moj Why do you want to pop each element out when you can remove the entire list in one line with `list.clear()`?

Comment: @Moj BTW, it would be `(*it)->source` and `nodeKeeper.pop_front()`

Comment: actually I am trying to write A-start search for some kind of language processing and I need to keep track of all my best translation. So in each step I need to pop the top element (after sorting base on best score) , remove it,and make some new element and  push new element to my list.

Comment: @Moj Does my update help now? I read the data with `cout<< (*it)->source` then I pop it out with `nodeKeeper.pop_front()`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks @David , helped a lot. I would give you more score If I could:D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24733/discussion-between-david-and-moj)